# Tabs content file image preview script not working

Tags: javascript, image, while-loop, jquery-ui-tabs, preview

Image preview function works correctly on the first tab, why doesn't it work on other tabs, I'm reloading the image preview function by clicking the tab, I couldn't find an example in the net for this problem.
Is there any idea?

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
      $( function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    } );
    
    function PreviewImage() {
    var count   = $('.tab-content').data('id');
    var preview = document.getElementById('uploadPreview_'+count);
    var file    = document.getElementById('uploadImage_'+count).files[0];
    var reader  = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        preview.src = reader.result;
    }, false);

    if (file) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
};

$(document).on('click', '#tab',function(e){
    PreviewImage();
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="tabs">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-toggle="tabs">
        <li id="tab"><a href="#tabs-1"> tab 1</a></li>
        <li id="tab"><a href="#tabs-2"> tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1" class="tab-content" data-id="1">
     <img id="uploadPreview_1" src="" alt="background" class="img-responsive center-block widget-background" style="height: 180px; width: auto;"  alt="image-alt">
     <input id="uploadImage_1" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="PreviewImage();"/>

 </div>
 <div id="tabs-2" class="tab-content" data-id="2">
     <img id="uploadPreview_2" src="" alt="background" class="img-responsive center-block widget-background" style="height: 180px; width: auto;"  alt="image-alt">
     <input id="uploadImage_2" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="PreviewImage();"/>

 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Redmaster recommend you edit your question to have the final render HTML. Not the php server side. From there people can help.

Comment: I have edited, is it appropriate?

Comment: Red, run you code and the copy the HTML from the web browser. OR are you actually having a PHP problem?

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the function.

Comment: @Bibberty do you have an idea?

Comment: Well the PreviewImage method only ever looks at the same tab. It would be easier to fix if you post the final HTML. Cannot debug with PHP

Comment: here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/0oqehu9k/

Comment: Ok, we can work on this now. Give me 20min

Comment: Take a look at the code below. It is working now. I did stop using jQuery, it just complicates the code further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is working now.

I think it makes sense just by looking at code.

But you can see we need to pass context to preview image.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
});

function PreviewImage(tab) {
  var preview = tab.parentNode.querySelector('img');
  var file =  tab.files[0]; 
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }, false);

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
};

document.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  if(e.target.matches('input[type="file"]')) {
    console.log(e.target);
    PreviewImage(e.target);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-toggle="tabs">
      <!-- Corrected id : Should be unique / added class tab for click. -->
      <li id="tab1" class="tab"><a href="#tabs-1"> tab 1</a></li>
      <li id="tab2" class="tab"><a href="#tabs-2"> tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1" class="tab-content" data-id="1">
      <img id="uploadPreview_1" src="" alt="background" class="img-responsive center-block widget-background" style="height: 180px; width: auto;" alt="image-alt">
      <input id="uploadImage_1"  type="file" accept="image/*" />

    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2" class="tab-content" data-id="2">
      <img id="uploadPreview_2" src="" alt="background" class="img-responsive center-block widget-background" style="height: 180px; width: auto;" alt="image-alt">
      <input id="uploadImage_2"  type="file" accept="image/*" />

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. The script is weak, I think I should take the course.